# How to change to new line in tokenize problem in c

Tags: c

The output of the code is

```
This
is
an
apple."How are you doing? GREAT!!"
```

But I want it looks like the output below.

```
This
is
an
apple
.
"How are you doing? GREAT!!"
```

1. I want to change to the new line when meet "," or "."
2. Don't change to the new line in between "".(which I think I have successfully done?) )

How to fix the problem with this code below?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *tokenize(char *init) {
  char *p, *ret;
  static char *head = NULL;
  static int insidequotes = 0;
  
  if (head == NULL && init == NULL) return NULL;
  if (init != NULL){
  head = init;
  insidequotes = 0;}
  if (*head == '\0') return NULL;

p = head; ret = head;
  while (*p != '\0') {
    if (*p == '"') {
      insidequotes = !insidequotes;
    } else if (!insidequotes && *p == ' ') {
      *p = '\0';
      head = p + 1;
      return ret;
    }
    p++;
  }

  head = p;
  return ret;
}

int main(void) {
  char s[] = "This is an apple.\"How are you doing? GREAT!!\"";
  char *p;

  p = tokenize(s);
  while (p != NULL) {
    puts(p);
    p = tokenize(NULL);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't do anything special for the `.` character. You need to write some code. Nobody will write your code for you here, this is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to break at quotes as well, i.e. `a"a"a` getting tree instances of `a`?

Comment: You possibly might want to consider *escaped* quotes (within quotes), too (compare your sample string literal).

Comment: What about `else if(!insidequotes) { switch(*p) { case ' ': /*...*/ break; case '.': case ',': /*...*/ break; default: /* do nothing */ break; } }`? You could extend to any characters you're interested in. Or you check via `ispunct` (or some other appropriate function from `ctypes.h` header).

Comment: Any you might want to consider multiple punctuation marks succeeding one another – you you want individual tokens for these or combine them into a single token?

Comment: If you want to retain punctuation marks as individual tokens (grouped or not) you need to consider, too, the case that these possibly are not followed by a space, so there's no character following to terminate the token! You might in that case remember the character at the next position in a separate variable, replace it by the null character as usual and extend the test case for the string end: `if(*head == 0) { if(original == 0) { return NULL; } *head = original; original = 0; }`. This would be fine, too, for breaking strings with internal quotes (`a"a"a`, see a previous comment of mine).

Comment: By the way: In your examples you are not breaking at newlines, but at spaces. You might, though, want to break at *any* whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, ...). If so, `isspace` function (from `ctypes.h`) is your friend. And you don't consider multiple spaces either. You'd return empty strings in between these currently, is this intended?

Comment: "Change to the new line" apparently means "write a newline character (`'\n'`)."  So do that where appropriate.

Comment: And going a bit in advance: *If* you opt for one of the functions from `ctypes.h` make sure you cast the characters to `unsigned char` before calling (e.g. `if(isspace((unsigned char)*p)) { /*...*/ }` – the function accepts `int` and as raw `char` being signed or unsigned is implementation defined you get wrong behaviour for characters in the extended ASCII range (> 127) if on your system `char` is signed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No – apparently it shall be an extended `strtok` which the usage within `main` reveals ;)

Comment: Just cosmetics, I personally would have written `for(char* p = tokenize(s); p; p = tokenize(NULL) } { puts(p); }` – just for the case you might like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `tokenize()` function split input string according to the given delimiter (which is `' '` in your code) and return token.

> *1. I want to change to the new line when meet "," or "."*

In `tokenize()` function, if you replace the hardcoded `' '` delimiter character with null-terminated string identifying delimiters and include `'.'` and `','` character in delimiters and add it's handling, your input string will be split when `'.'` character encounter. The only additional work you have to do is to return the string having only delimiter character in the next call of `tokenize()` function.

For this, along with null-terminated delimiter string, you can have another string which hold the delimiters to print. The content (characters) of this string should be subset of delimiter string. With this, the `tokenize()` function will be aware of the delimiters to print and act accordingly.

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *tokenize (char *init, const char * d, const char * pd) {
    char *p, *ret;
    static char *head = NULL;
    static int insidequotes = 0;
    static char pd_str[2];
    static char delimchar_p = '\0';
  
    if ((head == NULL) && (init == NULL)) return NULL;

    if (init != NULL) {
        head = init;
        insidequotes = 0;
    }

    if ((*head == '\0') && (delimchar_p == '\0')) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (delimchar_p) {
        pd_str[0] = delimchar_p;
        pd_str[1] = '\0';
        delimchar_p = '\0';
        return pd_str;
    }

    p = head; ret = head;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        if (*p == '"') {
            insidequotes = !insidequotes;
        } else if (!insidequotes && (d && strchr (d, *p))) {
            if (pd && strchr (pd, *p)) {
                delimchar_p = *p;
            }
            *p = '\0';
            head = p + 1;
            return ret;
        }
        p++;
    }

    head = p;
    return ret;
}

int main (void) {
    char s[] = "This is an apple.\"How are you doing? GREAT!!\"";
    char *p;
    char *delim = " .,";
    char *print_delim = ".";  //print_delim should be subset of delim

    p = tokenize (s, delim, print_delim);
    while (p != NULL) {
        puts(p);
        p = tokenize (NULL, delim, print_delim);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out 
This
is
an
apple
.
"How are you doing? GREAT!!"
```

**TODO** for you -

- Do you know that your code end up printing empty string if the first character  of input string is delimiter character or if there are more than one delimiter character exists in input string consecutively.... ?
  Leaving it up to you to handle these scenarios, if the behavior *not* intentional.